# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 0].Any suggestions will be helpful

Tags: python

### Below is the full error statement

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_18/2800853389.py in 
4 train_files, test_files, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(all_files,
5                                                                       label_array,
----> 6                                                                       random_state = 10, test_size = 0.1
7                                                                      )
8

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(test_size, train_size, random_state, shuffle, stratify, *arrays)
2415         raise ValueError("At least one array required as input")
2416
-> 2417     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
2418
2419     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
376
377     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 378     check_consistent_length(*result)
379     return result
380

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
332         raise ValueError(
333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
335         )
336

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 0]
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 0].
I am getting his error on the line which contains random_state.

```
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
label_array=[]
all_files = os.listdir()
train_files, test_files, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(all_files, 
                                                                      label_array,
                                                                      random_state = 10, test_size = 0.5
                                                                     )
plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix(y_true=test_labels[:len(pred)], y_pred=pred), 
                      classes=label_dict.keys())
```

Comment: At which like does the error happen? Can you post the full error statement.

Comment: `all_files = os.listdir(); label_array=[]; train_test_split(all_files, label_array)` is that really correct? What are you trying to do?

Probably all_files has two values, and label arras is empty produces the uneven match error.

Comment: `os.listdir()` produces a list of strings with the names of the files in _path_, which in this case is your working directory. `train_test_split` is not going to open these files for you, you need to write the code to do that. Actually, you are telling `train_test_split` that your training database is a list of directory names and your test database is an empty list.